# Is there a way to scroll text when readonly is True

Tags: python, kivy

I have this .kv code, it scrolls when read only is false, but when read only is true, it doesn't scroll.
Please how can I make it to scroll with read only set as true.
Thanks

```
enter code here <January1Window>:
name: "January1"
scroll:scroll
direction:'tb-lr'
size:(1480, 854)
ScrollView:
    id:scroll
    bar_color:(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
    bar_inactiv_color:(0, 0, 0.7, 0.4)
    bar_margin:2
    bar_width:8
    on_scroll_x:January1.focus = True
    on_scroll_y:January1.focus = True
    TextInput:
        size_hint:(0.8, 0.5)
        id:January1
        text: root.showJanuary1()
        padding:50
        readonly: True
        do_scroll_x:True
        do_scroll_y:True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.4, 'center_y':0.35}
        #background_color: 3,0,0.2, 0.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'
Label:
    text: 'Scroll TextInput'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 48
ToggleButton:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 48
    text: 'Set Read-Only'
    on_state: text_input.readonly = True if self.state else False
ScrollView:

    bar_color:(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
    bar_inactiv_color:(0, 0, 0.7, 0.4)
    bar_margin:2
    bar_width:8
    do_scroll_x:True
    do_scroll_y:True
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
        size_hint: .8, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        text: 'This is a long long long set of words\\n' * 100
```

Thanks to Elliot Garbus

Comment: Make sure to update your question to let everyone know! Also, don't post code-only answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any effect from the value of `readonly`. However, you need to set the `size_hint` to `None` for directions where you want to scroll. For example:

```
    TextInput:
        size_hint:(0.8, None)
        height: self.minimum_height
```

Comment: you are not scrolling the ScrollView, you are only scrolling textinput.